# How can i have 2 input if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

i want it so if is_male == "Y": and if is_male == "N": also works when they you type y and n (with no capslocks)

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
age = input("Enter your age: ")
is_male = input("Are you a man? Y/N: ")
if is_male == "Y":
    print("Your name is " + name + " you are " + age + " years old and you are a male.")
if is_male == "N":
    print("Your name is " + name + " you are " + age + " years old and you are a female.")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if is_male.lower() == "y":
    ...

if is_male.lower() == 'n':
    ...
```

This will make it case insensitive so it works for both `Y` and `y`.

Comment: Or instead of calling `str.lower` 2x, just call it when you get `input`

Comment: @Jab yeah that works too !

Answer (score 0):

You can change like this.

if is_male == "Y": -> if is_male == "Y" or is_male == "y":

if is_male == "N": -> if is_male == "N" or is_male == "n":

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `is_male` a `bool`? The value would fit it's variable name more appropriately. You can do that when you ask for input:

```
is_male = input("Are you a man? Y/N: ").upper() == 'Y'
```

Then your if statement would be:

```
if is_male:
    ...
else:
    ...
```